# Connecting to an SQL DB using PowerShell and showing results in textbox.text

Tags: mysql, forms, powershell, visual-studio-2019

I can connect to my DB using `PS ISE` and it shows the results i need in the console area, when i try to transfer it over to `Visual Studios 2019` and get the results to show in the `textbox` the only thing is shows is the `query` instead of the results. please see image and code below.

[image]

```
$button21_Click = {

$button21.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = "LawnGreen"
$button21.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = "2"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll")
$MySQLConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = “server=********;port=********;user id=*********;password=**********;database=wordpressdb**87;pooling=false”
$MySQLConnection.Open()
$query1 = 'SELECT  order_item_id , order_item_name , order_id  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = 25696 ' 
Invoke-MySqlQuery  -Query $query1 -Verbose
$textbox17.text = $query1 
$MySQLConnection.close()
}
```

This is what it shows when i use `PS ISE` and this is what i want to see in my `textbox`

[image]

**After following Andrews Advice and tweaking it a little i now have the correct number of line but the value is showing `System.Data.DataRow`
this is the New code i have changed the `textbox` to a `listbox` as well**

```
**$Global:MySQLConnection.Open()
$query1 = 'SELECT  *  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = 25696 ' 
$queryResults = Invoke-MySqlQuery  -Query $query1 -Verbose
Foreach($query in $queryResults){
$listbox1.Items.Add($query)
$Global:MySQLConnection.close()
}
}**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a day of research and headache i have compiled the solution. please see working code below.

to change the order it shows in the `listbox` you only need to change the `$results`

```
$button21_Click = {

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll")
$MySQLConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$MySQLConnection.ConnectionString=“server=********;port=********;userid=*********;password=**********;database=wordpressdb**87;pooling=false”
$MySQLConnection.Open()

$query1 = Invoke-MySqlQuery "SELECT  order_item_id, order_item_name , order_id  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = 25696 " 
$result = $query1 | %{"$($_.order_item_id)    $($_.order_id)   $($_.order_item_name)"}
Foreach($res in $result){
$listBox8.Items.Add($res)

 }                                                                             
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be assigning the value of the textbox to the string containing the query. You want to change the textbox to contain what the query returns.

```
$query1 = 'SELECT  order_item_id , order_item_name , order_id  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = 25696 ' 
$queryResults = Invoke-MySqlQuery  -Query $query1 -Verbose
$textbox17.text = $queryResults
$MySQLConnection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for this but still no joy, it wont show anything now any other ideas